# Compiling error when initializing excel with dependant ActiveX Comboboxes

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

Good afternoon!
I'm an extreme newbie when it comes to coding, and i've been dabbling a little with Excel VBA for a project i want to make for my boss.
It's something quite simple, but it took me a while to understand everything that's going on, but i got it to work.

Summary: There's table with three levels of sub-items (So 1 / 1.1 / 1.1.1) and i've managed to make three comboboxes where 3 is dependant on what you pick on 2, and 2 is dependant on what you pick on 1; So if i pick 1 on CB1, it opens up the sub-items for 1 (1.1) and if i pick 1.1 on CB2, it opens up 1.1.1 on three
They need to be ActiveX comboboxes becase my map is big, and when i zoom out i need it to be big, which i cant do with data validation dependant lists.

The issue i'm facing is, every other time i save and close the workbook, when it launches, it shows a compile error in CB1 sub.
What i think is happening is when i open the workbook, for some reason it only understands that CB1 exists, but no CB2/CB3, so when it sees a reference to CB2/CB3 on the CB1 sub, it shows a compile error because CB/CB3 technically dont exist yet?
Then as soon as i close the VBA editor, it understands those two exist, and i dont get an error anymore, until i close/launch the workbook 2 times, and it repeats.

This is the code i have:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox3.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N3" Then
        If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value Then
        Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox2.Clear
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N2" Then
        If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Me.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N1" Then
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i


End Sub
```

The compile error is in this line every other time i launch the workbook:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")
    
    Dim i As Integer
    
    Me.ComboBox2.Clear
    Me.ComboBox3.Clear
```

I appreciate any inputs that could help me with this project. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `Worksheet_Activate()` event is calling `ComboBox1_Change` when it gets to the line `Me.ComboBox1.Clear`

Could you try something and tell me the result?
Change the relevant parts of code like this:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N3" Then
        If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = Me.ComboBox2.Value Then
        Me.ComboBox3.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.ComboBox2.Clear
Me.ComboBox3.Clear

For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N2" Then
        If sh.Range("C" & i).Value = Me.ComboBox1.Value Then
        Me.ComboBox2.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub



Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
Me.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "N1" Then
        Me.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, so I think the error you're getting it's because it can't find the ActiveX control somehow.

You should try again by fully qualifying the comboBoxes.

Now, where exactly are located the comboBoxes?
On which sheet? If the comboBoxes are all in the `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")` sheet, then you should change

```
Me.ComboBox2.Clear
Me.ComboBox3.Clear
```

to:

```
sh.ComboBox2.Clear
sh.ComboBox3.Clear
```

Also, I would suggest that if you want to populate your ComboBox1 automatically as the workbook opens, that you move the code inside `Worksheet_Activate()` to `Private Sub Workbook_Open()` that should be placed inside the `ThisWorkbook` object under your Microsoft Excel Objects

So, replace all of your `Me.` by `sh.`
Let me know how this change works out for you.

**UPDATE2:**

Ok, I just tested myself with your code, in order to correct the code and make it work, try using the codename of the sheet.
See the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8yQf.jpg

Also you can edit the codename of the sheet and change it.
If you don't see the Properties tab then you can press F4 and make it appear or doing the same thing through the View tab.

In my case the sheet named First Page, it's codename is Sheet1.

So I changed the code like this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")

Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To sh.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If sh.Range("A" & i).Value = "example1" Then
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

And this way the error you had dissapeared, by the way, you can further optimize your code by refering to the sheet by it's codename alltogether, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False
Sheet1.ComboBox1.Clear
For i = 2 To Sheet1.Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    If Sheet1.Range("A" & i).Value = "example1" Then
        Sheet1.ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
    End If
Next i

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Also, you can further optimize the code by using with, like this:

```
Dim i As Integer

Application.EnableEvents = False

With Sheet1
    .ComboBox1.Clear
    For i = 2 To .Range("A" & Application.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If .Range("A" & i).Value = "example1" Then
            .ComboBox1.AddItem sh.Range("B" & i)
        End If
    Next i
End With

Application.EnableEvents = True
```

Finally, the reason why the second time it "recognizes" that the comboBoxes exists it's because after running the code a first time `sh` was at least once set to be `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Listas")`, now the `sh` variable ceases to exist outside of the subs, as it is a local variable, but I think and given that it was set already once, and you didn't write `set sh = nothing` anywhere, that actually somewhere in the memory excel "remembers" the sheet.

In your case it's the same thing with the Me keyword I think, and that's why the second time it works.

Let me know how this latest UPDATE2 works for you.

Comment: Replaced my code for yours, and the same error happens
https://imgur.com/a/RPgBege

Comment: @Lopz0r Could you also share the actual error?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/S2MJaqN
Sorry that it's in portuguese, but it roughly translates to "Compile error: Method or Data member not found"

Comment: It's interesting that when i check the subs in that worksheet when the error prompts, it only shows Combobox1 as a sub; upon closing the VBA editor, and say, selecting something from the drop down menus of the comboboxes, and then going back to the editor, it recognizes that there are 3 comboboxes https://imgur.com/a/pffuvXf

Comment: @Lopz0r Forget the first UPDATE, just use UPDATE2 and tell me if it works for you.